# Android simultaneous download and unzip

Tags: android, download, local-storage, unzip, simultaneous

I have a really large zip file (approx 3GB) that I would like to download onto the user's device, but I also need to unzip it.

The problem is that in reality I need double this space free on local storage, so that the zip file can first be downloaded and then for it to be unzipped accordingly. This means that for the entire process to be successful the user would need at least 6GB of free space. This is highly unlikely to be the case on a mobile device.

One potential solution is to unzip the file as it is being downloaded, so that only 3GB of free space is needed. Is this possible on Android and if so, how?

Are there other file types that would be more appropriate for this situation?

Or if you guys have any other ideas about downloading such a large amount of data then please let me know.

Thanks.